# Django REST frameworkでHTTPステータスコード500

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Django REST frameworkについて質問です。

現在、ユーザのパスワード変更するAPIを作成しております。

APIには引数として以下3つをリクエストします。

*- 現在のパスワード (old_password)

- 新しいパスワード (new_password)
- 新しいパスワード(確認用) (new_password_confirm)*

APIの処理の流れとしては以下になります。

*1. 新しいパスワード(new_password)と新しいパスワード(確認用)(new_password_confirm)の入力値が同じかチェック

2. 現在のパスワード(old_password)と対象ユーザのDB登録値パスワードが同じチェック

3. 新しいパスワード(new_password)でユーザ情報を更新する*

しかしながら現在APIのHTTPレスポンスのステータスコードが500を返します。
###HTTPレスポンスログ

```
XXX.XX.X.X - - [DD/MM/YYYY:HH:MM:SS +0000] "PATCH /api/password_change/1/ HTTP/1.1" 500 13596 "-" "python-requests/2.21.0" "-"
```

以下view.py、serializer.py、urls.pyのどのクラスにHTTPエラーの原因があるのか検討もつきません。

解決策でなく、気づきレベルの亊でも構いません。

何卒ご教授のほどよろしくお願いいたします。

#### views.py

```
class ChangePassView(generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView):

    queryset = User.objects.filter.all()
    serializer_class = ChangePassSerializer

    def patch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    
        old_password = request.POST["old_password"]
        new_password = request.POST["new_password"]
        new_password_confirm = request.POST["new_password_confirm"]

        if not new_password.equals(new_password_confirm):
             return JsonResponse({'message': '新しいパスワードが異なります'}, status=403)

        user = User.objects.get(id=kwargs['pk'])

        if not user.check_password(old_password):
             return JsonResponse({'message': '現在のパスワードが異なります'}, status=403)

        return super().update(new_password, kwargs['pk'])
```

#### models.py

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    user_Id = models.CharField(_('user_Id'), max_length=7, unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(_('password'), max_length=255)
```

#### serializer.py

```
class ChangePassSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    old_password = serializers.CharField(max_length=255)
    new_password = serializers.CharField(max_length=255)
    new_password_confirm = serializers.CharField(max_length=255)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('password',)

    def update(self, user, validated_data):
        user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
        user.save()
        return user
```

#### urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
  app_name = 'api'
  path('password_change/<int:pk>/', ChangePassView.as_view(),
        name='password_change'),
]
```

### 2019/06/12 追記

WebサーバにはNginxを使用しております。
APIにリクエストを送った時に出るエラーログは以下になります。
※ 日付とIPアドレスはマスクしております。

#### /var/log/nginx/error.log

```
YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM:SS [info] 9#9: *33 client closed connection while waiting for request, client: XXX.XX.X.X, server: X.X.X.X:80
YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM:SS [info] 9#9: *40 client XXX.XX.X.X closed keepalive connection
YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM:SS [info] 9#9: *42 client XXX.XX.X.X closed keepalive connection
```

### 2019/06/15 追記

django.logに出力されているエラーメッセージは以下になります。

#### django.log

```
File "./api/views.py", line 65, in patch
  if not new_password.equals(new_password_confirm):
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'equals'
```

### 2019/06/17 追記

views.pyを以下に修正したところ、エラー箇所が変わりました。

#### views.py

```
class ChangePassView(generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView):

    queryset = User.objects.filter.all()
    serializer_class = ChangePassSerializer

    def patch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        old_password = request.POST["old_password"]
        new_password = request.POST["new_password"]
        new_password_confirm = request.POST["new_password_confirm"]

        if new_password != (new_password_confirm):
             return JsonResponse({'message': '新しいパスワードが異なります'}, status=403)

        user = User.objects.get(id=kwargs['pk'])

        if not user.check_password(old_password):
             return JsonResponse({'message': '現在のパスワードが異なります'}, status=403)

        return super().update(new_password, kwargs['pk'])
```

#### django.log(エラーメッセージ)

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 495, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 455, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 492, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "./api/views.py", line 76, in patch
    return super().update(new_password, kwargs['pk'])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py", line 68, in update
    serializer = self.get_serializer(instance, data=request.data, partial=partial)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'data'
```

親クラスのmixins.pyでAttributeErrorが発生しているようです。
（mixins.py 68行目 下記貼り付け箇所だと8行目)

#### mixins.py

```
class UpdateModelMixin(object):
    """
    Update a model instance.
    """
    def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        partial = kwargs.pop('partial', False)
        instance = self.get_object()
        serializer = self.get_serializer(instance, data=request.data, partial=partial)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_update(serializer)

        if getattr(instance, '_prefetched_objects_cache', None):
            # If 'prefetch_related' has been applied to a queryset, we need to
            # forcibly invalidate the prefetch cache on the instance.
            instance._prefetched_objects_cache = {}

        return Response(serializer.data)

    def perform_update(self, serializer):
        serializer.save()

    def partial_update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['partial'] = True
        return self.update(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

#### 2019/06/18追記

AttributeErrorに関しては別質問としてを以下リンクに登録致しました。
[Django REST frameworkでAttributeError](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/55888/django-rest-framework%E3%81%A7attributeerror)

Comment: HTTPステータス500は内部サーバーエラーなので、何かしらエラーメッセージがログに出力されているはずです。ログを確認して、エラーの要因と思われる箇所をこの質問に追記して下さい。

Comment: Kohei TAMURA様
ご指摘頂きありがとうございます。
エラーの要因と思われるログを追記致しました。

Comment: Nginxではなく、Djangoのログを見たいです。おそらく`settings.py`を見れば、ログの出力先が書いてあると思いますが。

Comment: Kohei TAMURA様
対応が遅くなってしまい申し訳ございません。
django.logのエラー文を記載致しました。

元々ログ出力の設定を行っていなかった亊もあり
時間がかかってしまいました。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pythonの文字列比較は`==`ですね。`equals`ではなく。つまり、

```py
if not new_password.equals(new_password_confirm):
```

の行は、

```
if new_password != new_password_confirm:
```

が正しいです。

Comment: Kohei TAMURA様
ご回答頂きありがとうございます。
ご回答内容の修正を行いましたところ
別の箇所でエラーが発生致しました。
(※ 

自己解決出来るよう取り組んでおりますが
先日1日では解決出来ませんでした。
(※ 2019/06/17 追記以下)

もしよろしければ、再度ご助力頂く亊は可能でしょうか?

Comment: おそらくDjango RFの仕様に合わない実装（例えば、継承の仕方とか）をしていることに起因していると思います。が、質問が当初のものと変わり、長くなってきたので、いったんこの質問はクローズして新たな質問を登録していただけないでしょうか？私以外の人が見る機会も増えると思います。

Comment: Kohei TAMURA様
アドバイス頂きありがとうございます。
AttributeErrorは別質問として、登録致しました。

本質問に関して、ご回答及び様々なご指摘を頂きまことにありがとうございました。

Comment: @osamaster さん、一旦 `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'equals'` というエラーに対してはこの回答で解決できたようですので、回答の承認をお願いします。
[自分の質問に誰かが回答してくれたらどうしたらいいですか？ - ヘルプ センター - スタック・オーバーフロー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)